# Encountering Token Limit Error (14801 tokens) when using OpenAI Model for Data Extraction

Tags: python, openai-api, langchain, chatgpt-api, py-langchain

I'm attempting to use an OpenAI model to extract data from text, but I keep running into an error message that says, "your messages resulted in 14801 tokens. Please reduce the length of the messages." Can someone guide me on how to address this token limit issue and successfully extract the data I need?

My main goal is to apply the same logic that was applied on small text on the entire pdf text.
So i can get meangful data.

1. is there any way to avoid this? i was thinking some good text summraztion techniques maybe
2. can the entire text be used as it's but devide it do some chunks and stream to the model with inital prompt?
3. i think using vector database can be usefull here? any ideas.
4. also is there any good utils in langchain to clean up text?

and thanks for time and help <3.

**This is my notebook playground:**
[notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1MErWMfc1tfoYiM3_vD1aBkbsKnJV3o8a?usp=sharing)

**This the pdf that i used for testing:**
[text](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OjvOIGSFHE7SJy_jromuEpxA7TshFl1o/view?usp=sharing)